# Yii2-dynamic form

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app, dynamicform

I'm using yii2-advanced-app. I've problem as shown on following snap - [image: problem snapshot]

If I select any main category, all the sub categories are changing instead of only the corresponding one.

My view code is as follows -

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Add More Categories</h4></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                     <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                        'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                        'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                        'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                        'limit' => 4, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                        'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                        'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                        'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                        'model' => $modelsBusinessSubCategories[0],
                        'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                        'formFields' => [
                            'bmc_id',
                            'bsc_name',
                        ],
                    ]); ?>

                    <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
                        <?php foreach ($modelsBusinessSubCategories as $i => $modelsBusinessSubCategories): ?>
                            <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Categories</h3>
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <?php
                                        // necessary for update action.
                                        if (!$modelsBusinessSubCategories->isNewRecord) {
                                            echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelsBusinessSubCategories, "[{$i}]id");
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_main_category_id')->dropDownList(
                                            ArrayHelper::map(BusinessMainCategories::find()->all(), 'bmc_id', 'bmc_name'),
                                            [
                                                'prompt' => 'Select Main Category',
                                                'onchange' => '
                                                    $.post("index.php?r=business-sub-categories/lists&id=' . '"+$(this).val(),function(data){
                                                        $("select#vendors-ven_sub_category_id").html(data);
                                                    });'])
                                        ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_sub_category_id')->dropDownList(
                                            ArrayHelper::map(BusinessSubCategories::find()->all(), 'bsc_id', 'bsc_name'),
                                            [
                                                'prompt' => 'Select Sub Category'
                                            ]);
                                        ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- .row -->                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also, After clicking on 'Add' button, it shows the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'widgetItem' of undefined` in `yii2-dynamic-form.js`.

Where am I going wrong? please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java script for action event... use bind to avoid multiple fire

Answer (score 0):

Your form and model both are some or not? I meant to say your form is belong different model and your pass different model.